# .htaccess rewrite rule not working for index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am trying to use pretty urls so `https://example.com/event/1/dog-singing` will load `https://example.com/events?action=show&id=1`

I added the following code to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ events?action=show&id=$1 [L,NC]
```

I get a 404 page.

I tried using

```
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ index\.php/events?action=show&id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Same 404 page.

The below rewrite works. But I don't want to load the script from the subdirectory.

```
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ wp-content/plugins/testplugin/testplugin\.php?action=show&id=$1 [L,NC]
```

The one below also works. But it changes the pretty url in the address bar.

```
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/events?action=show&id=$1 [L,NC]
```

**EDIT**

Here is the full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]*)/[^/]*/?$ index.php?action=show&id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^register/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ wp-content/plugins/testplugin/testplugin\.php?action=register&event=$1&name=$2 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Internal rewrites won't work with Wordpress. Use WP rewrite API inside your theme.

Comment: @anubhava thank you for the tip. I will try the WP rewrite API. However I am at a loss why the second rewrite works "wp-content/plugins/testplugin/testplugin\.php?action=register&event=$1&name=$2 [L]" but not the first. Thanks.